# canceling downloads using AFNetworking with cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, afnetworking

I'm stuck canceling downloads with AFNetworking. In my app, the user can trigger single movie downloads this way:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                                         {
                                             //do success stuff

                                         }
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Error downloadMovie: %@", error);
                                         }];
[operation start];
```

That works fine. But how can I force a download to be stopped? I read about using this method:

```
cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod
```

If I use it this way, it doesn't do anything:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:@"http://www.xyz/mymovie.mp4"];
[client cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:nil path:@"http://www.xyz/mymovie.mp4"];
```

What would be the proper way to cancel the download?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`, which has a `-cancel` method. Use that.

Comment: By the way, that's not really how `AFHTTPClient` is supposed to be used. Base URL is the TLD, and path is a URL path. See the example project for an example. Also, you may want to use a `NSOperationQueue` property or shared singleton to manage any long-running operations.