# Interrupt executing AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking

How can I interrupt executing AFHTTPRequestOperation? Is this even possible if HTTP request is already started but no yet finished?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by interrupt? If you mean that you want to cancel the operation then just call `-cancel`. See: [canceling downloads using AFNetworking with cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676897/canceling-downloads-using-afnetworking-with-cancelallhttpoperationswithmethod-do).

Comment: the case: i start a http request with AFHTTPRequestOperation. i have success block, failure block and timeout, for example 15 seconds. And for some reason (for example, user pressed "cancel")  i want to stop this request immediately. If I just call [myOperation cancel] the request still will be active until i'll get response or the timeout'll occur.

Comment: @rudensm Something is not right, I think you need to post sample code.